# How to correctly call an event handler function in a parent component with a parameter in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a function in a component which I want to call in a child component.

This is the function in the parent component:

```
handleFilterGroupsQuery = queryObject => {
    return queryObject;
}
```

I have binded it to this in the constructor (in parent component):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFilterGroupsQuery = this.handleFilterGroupsQuery.bind(this);
}
```

Within the render method of this component, I am passing down this function to a child component like so:

```
<FilterGroupsSection 
    handleFilterGroupsQuery={(queryObject) => {this.handleFilterGroupsQuery(queryObject)}} 
/>
```

In the FilterGroupsSection (child) component, I am trying to call this function like so:

```
let test = 'test'
console.log(this.props.handleFilterGroupsQuery(test));
```

This displays 'undefined' in the console. I can't figure out why the parameter value is not being passed correctly.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options. Just remove additional {} in function binding to your child component or use return:

```
 handleFilterGroupsQuery={(queryObject) => this.handleFilterGroupsQuery(queryObject)}
```

or

```
 handleFilterGroupsQuery={(queryObject) => { return this.handleFilterGroupsQuery(queryObject)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One good solution would be to pass the argument and the function separately:

```
<Parent 
  handleFilterGroupsQuery={this.handleFilterGroupsQuery}
  queryObject={queryObject}
/>
```

Then, you can easily bind the argument every time you call the function at your child component:

```
this.props.handleFilterGroupsQuery.bind(null, queryObject);
```

Otherwise, the **unnamed inline functions and object** will have new references and trigger a complete re-render of the component tree below.